# запустить программу в планировщике от имени администратора

Tags: windows-7

можно ли как то под администратором создать задачу в планировщике, чтобы любой пользователь при входе в windows 7 получал приложение запущенное с правами администратора.
Планировщик позволяет создать такую задачу, но на практике не работает.

Comment: Вот ссылка где уже решили похожую проблему - http://forum.oszone.net/thread-326631.html

Comment: По ссылке предлагают запускать приложение от имени группы, а не от одного пользователя. Попробовал. Пока не смог запустить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 7 под рукой нет. На Windows 10 это выглядит так:

Имеется учётная запись admin, имеющая права администратора (не встроенный администратор!). Имеется учётная запись test, имеющая права обычного пользователя.

Создаю в папке C:\tmp батч-файл с именем test.bat следующего содержания:

```
cd /d %ProgramFiles%
md test
copy c:\tmp\test.bat .\test\*.*
```

Создаю с планировщике задание со следующими параметрами:

- При выполнении использовать учётную запись: admin
- Выполнять: для всех пользователей
- Триггер: При входе в систему - любого пользователя
- Действия: Запуск программы c:\tmp\test.bat

Сохраняю задание (при этом запрашивается ввод пароля учётной записи admin - ввожу). Выполняю вход пользователем test. Наблюдаю появление в каталоге C:\Program Files подкаталога tmp с файлом test.bat.

Comment: получилось. спасибо. там нюанс в том что визуально не увидишь запущенное приложение, я и не видел поэтому.Но не страшно, лишь бы работало.  Можно ли как то создать задачу в планировщике запустив скрипт (на этом этапе права администраторские есть)? Или скопировать рабочую задачу в планировщик другого компьютера (права тоже есть)?

Comment: *нюанс в том что визуально не увидишь запущенное приложение* Да, это так. Я не зря сказал "Наблюдается", и ни полслова - про окно консоли. Причём мне вообще не удалось вывести окно на экран, хотя формально управление им доступно (в processexplorer пункт Window-Bring to front). *Можно ли как то создать задачу в планировщике запустив скрипт?* Да, вполне. Всё, что делается руками, может делаться и программно. Но утилиты командной строки (AT, SCHTASKS) такой тип задания создавать не умеют - придётся использовать средства VBS или PS.

Comment: Можно подробнее? Я пока не сталкивался с этими средствами. Хотя бы полное название

Comment: VBS = Visual Basic Script, PS = PostScript. Работа с заданиями планировщика выполняется через объект "Schedule.Service".

Comment: Думаю там все равно придется вводить пароль администратора так или иначе. Мне не нужен именно планировщик . Мне нужен способ запустить скрипт с правами администратора. Вполне устроит программа в коде которой явно прописан пароль администратора. Аналог runus но без интерактивного ввода пароля. Если знаете как ее сделать, то подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: *Думаю там все равно придется вводить пароль администратора так или иначе.* Пароль, несомненно, придётся задавать литералом в коде создания задания. *Аналог runus но без интерактивного ввода пароля.* У RUNAS есть ключ /savecred. Хотя в этом случае один раз пароль ввести руками всё равно нужно. Но он неразборчив - можно будет запустить с этими учётными данными любое приложение.