# Настроить запуск приложения при загрузке с правами администратора

Tags: windows-7

Нужно чтобы при загрузке запускался скрипт с правами администратора. Как это сделать? Как то же запускаются драйвера и прочие процессы от имени системы. Хотелось бы чтобы мой процесс точно также запускался с правами системы или администратора. В реестре его где то прописать или еще как?

Comment: *Нужно чтобы при загрузке запускался скрипт* При загрузке ЧЕГО? станции, учётной записи (любой, определённой), приложения? *запускался скрипт с правами администратора* Точно - администратора? без повышения прав?

Comment: При входе любого пользователя в систему. Запускался с правами администратора.Или от имени системы. Нужно копировать файлы в Program Files. Для этого нужны права. Не знаю что такое повышение прав если честно.

Comment: *При входе любого пользователя в систему.* Это делается через планировщик. *Нужно копировать файлы в Program Files.* Настраиваете задание на выполнение от имени учётной записи администратора.

Comment: Про планировщик я спрашивал в другой теме. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1039387/запустить-программу-в-планировщике-от-имени-администратора А есть еще способы через реестр например?

Comment: *есть еще способы через реестр например?* Есть. Но лучше ими не пользоваться. Они требуют сохранения аутентификационной информации, а метод сохранения не слишком разборчив по части того, нафига его сохранили - в итоге тем же способом можно запустить от имени администратора фактически любое приложение.

Comment: ок. а через планировщик не получается в другой теме